# Powershell variable expansion along with a single quote

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

In the expression below I would like $key variable to be expanded to 
"//configuration[@navtitle=**'Some Report'**]"

How do I achieve that? know that $key value is derived from external file

```
$key = "Some Report"
Xml.SelectNodes("//configuration[@title=$key]")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes won't be parsed within double quotes. You could put the single quotes in $key or the string:

```
$key = "'Some Report'"
"//configuration[@title=$key]"
```

Output:

```
//configuration[@title='Some Report']
```

OR

```
$key = "Some Report"
"//configuration[@title='$key']"
```

Comment: Last one worked. First one doesn't apply because as I said I derive $key value from external source without single quote.